# My python script as in cron job in docker container fail to writefiles

Tags: python-3.x, docker, cron, writefile

I have a simple python script that runs a sql query and converts the query results into `csv` (and `parquet`) leveraging `pandas.to_csv(path/to/csv-file)` (and `pandas.to_parquet(path/to/parquet-file)`

I'm using Docker Desktop in Windows 10. I have WSL installed -which I believe Docker Desktop somehow connects to that.

My python script 'main.py`:

```
import vertica_python as vp
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

connection_settings = {
    'host': 'host.host',
    'port': 5433,
    'user': "user",
    'password': "password",
    'database': 'db'
}

def pull_data_vertica():

    sql_file = "sample.sql"
    with open(sql_file) as f:
        query = f.read()

    connection = vp.connect(**connection_settings)

    temp = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
    connection.close()

    _pre = "/app/data_from_vertical_"
    _dt = dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')

    csv_out = _pre + _dt + '.csv'
    temp.to_csv(csv_out)
    
    parquet_out = _pre + _dt + '.parquet'
    temp.to_parquet(parquet_out)
    
    return csv_out, parquet_out

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b = pull_data_vertica()
```

The  Dcokerfile is as following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.8 python3-pip python3-dev cron vim busybox
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 -q install pip --upgrade
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN rm requirements.txt
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY script/main.py main.py
COPY script/sample.sql sample.sql
RUN chmod 0644 /app/main.py
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

here is my `crontab`:

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py
```

I `docker build` the image, then `docker run` it in detached mode, and by `docker exe ... bash` I get into the container bash.

In there, I can manually execute my `main.py` and everything works. However, the cron job seems to be failing to produce the csv file, i.e., no file is written. I also don't have access to any `log` file to check if there is any issue with the cron job.

notes:

1. I see `cron` is the main process in the container (using `top`).
2. I did try to put the corntab content in a `.sh` script and execute that but all is the same with above: the `.sh` alone runs perfectly and files are written, however in the cronjob nothing happens.
3. I added shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on top of `main.py` script.

Update:

I installed `busybox` and modified the last line of Dockerfile to the following:

```
CMD busybox syslogd && cron -f
```

then in the container, I found the content `/var/log/messages` as following:

```
Oct 28 02:11:59 0ad085300c89 syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.30.1
Oct 28 02:11:59 0ad085300c89 cron.info cron[9]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 28 02:11:59 0ad085300c89 cron.err cron[9]: Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/crontab
Oct 28 02:11:59 0ad085300c89 cron.info cron[9]: (*system*crontab) ERROR (Syntax error, this crontab file will be ignored)
Oct 28 02:11:59 0ad085300c89 cron.info cron[9]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 28 02:12:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.err CRON[10]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Oct 28 02:12:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[10]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 02:12:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[11]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull^M)
Oct 28 02:12:02 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[10]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 02:12:02 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[10]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 02:12:31 0ad085300c89 cron.info crontab[37]: (root) LIST (root)
Oct 28 02:13:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.err CRON[40]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Oct 28 02:13:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[40]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 02:13:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[41]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull^M)
Oct 28 02:13:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[40]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 02:13:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[40]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 02:14:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.err CRON[59]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Oct 28 02:14:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[59]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 02:14:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[60]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull^M)
Oct 28 02:14:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[59]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 02:14:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[59]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 02:15:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.err CRON[81]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Oct 28 02:15:01 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[81]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 02:15:01 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[82]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull^M)
Oct 28 02:15:02 0ad085300c89 cron.info CRON[81]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 02:15:02 0ad085300c89 authpriv.info CRON[81]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I am not sure I clearly get what cron is upset for but hope it helps.

Update 2:
Thanks to @jabbson 's comment I updfate the following:

1. absolute path to output file: `/app/...` instead of `./..`
2. crontab is  `* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1`
3. here is the new `/var/log/messages` content:

```
Oct 28 03:10:36 898c63c3a4e6 syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.30.1
Oct 28 03:10:36 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info cron[10]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Oct 28 03:10:36 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info cron[10]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[20]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[21]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[22]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[23]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[20]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[21]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[21]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 03:11:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[20]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[25]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[26]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[27]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[28]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[25]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[26]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[25]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 03:12:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[26]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[32]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[33]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[34]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[35]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py pull >> /app/exec.log 2>&1^M)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[33]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 cron.info CRON[32]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[32]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 28 03:13:01 898c63c3a4e6 authpriv.info CRON[33]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

4. AND NOTHING!!!!!! no log file in `/app`
5. Tried the same in Mac OS and it works in there. So this is not related to `dataframe.to_csv` (or `dataframe.to_parquet`) but I assume related to Docker  Desktop on Windows and Docker Daemon.

I appreciate if you could kindly assist me with this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: Since I do not know what's in the main.py, i wrote my own, which opens a file and appends a timestamp, then built an image and ran it. Every minute I see a new line in the file. Everything is exactly the same as in your example. Could the problem be with your main.py?

Comment: thanks @jabbson. Ill update the post with my main.py.

Comment: what if you write the output of executing your script into a file? something like
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py >> /app/exec.log 2>&1

Comment: and then wait for the a minute to see if you get that exec.log

Comment: Changing the `crontab` as said `* * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /app/main.py >> /app/exec.log 2>&1` and will update the comment with regards to results. I have added `root` at the beginning of the command.

Comment: Also I've noticed your script uses sample.sql, but I do not see you copying it to the container

Comment: I must have dropped it to remove comment for the purpose of this post. It is indeed copied and the script run manual outside of cron.

Comment: I'd also specify the absolute path to this file in the script

Comment: I the changes above and waited for a few minutes. log file is cleaner but NOTHING. Its weird

Comment: I was in the chat, but I guess you weren't. I see from the logs you showed, that there is an ^M at the end of the line in your crontab file, did you create it in windows?